# ubuntu to raspberry-pi bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I am trying to connect a laptop running ubuntu 14.05 to a raspberry pi using bluetooth. All I want to be able to do is to send a few kilobytes of data back and forth between the devices.

I have installed bluez on the pi and have made it discoverable using:

`$ sudo hciconfig hci0 piscan`

```
 $ hciconfig
 hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:19:0E:17:A7:CA  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN
    RX bytes:16543 acl:220 sco:0 events:570 errors:0
    TX bytes:9467 acl:212 sco:0 commands:206 errors:0
```

Next I used `bluez-simple-agent` to pair successfully with the laptop. I can ping the pi fine using `sudo l2ping XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` from ubuntu.

When I try to open a serial port to the pi I get this:

```
$ sudo rfcomm connect 0 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Connected /dev/rfcomm0 to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX on channel 1
Press CTRL-C for hangup
Disconnected
```

This all happens very quickly and from what it tells me, it connected successfully then disconnected straight away... why? I can't do anything with the rfcomm0 port if it disconnects immediately.